# Perfmon issue, no application counters on Report.html

Tags: performance-monitor, perfmon

Can anyone help me on this issue I encountered on a Windows Server 2019 regarding reporting on Perfmon using performance counters?

I've tried to monitor the utilization of our IIS servers using counters in a Windows 2019 server but when I check the generated report, there's no application counters in the generated report.

[image: No application counter report]

I've tried to replicate this to another server and there's an application counters on it, unlike on this specific windows 2019 server. Here's the screenshot of another server where in I tried to replicate to generate a report. It shows an application counters unlike on the other server.

[image: with application counters]

Any workaround/solution on this one?

Comment: Have you tried to manually rebuild your performance counters using `lodctr.exe /R` ?  You may need to rebuild performance counters for both 64-bit (%windir%\system32\) and 32-bit (%windir%\SysWOW64\) performance counters.

Comment: Also, review the raw Report.HTML in a text editor, to ensure the performance counter data is actually missing.  Microsoft products are notorious for generating terribly formatted HTML, which sometimes causes rendering issues in non-Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: Hi Lee, yes already tried to rebuild the counters by using this command lodctr /R and restarting the Performance Logs and Alerts and WMI services but still no avail.